# Como implemento el total de combinaciones en este ejercicio

Tags: python-3.x

buen dia , necesito hacer la mayor cantidad de combinaciones posibles , ejemplo en las variables asigno 1,2,3  y  4,5,6 y que me genere en la nueva lista las combinaciones, 1,1  1,2  1,3  1,4 1,5 1,6 asi, pero no logro conectar la tercera lista, alguien puede ayudarme?

```
print ("Bienvenido al combinador")
a= (int(input("Ingrese los numeros de la 1 lista:")))
b= (int(input("Ingrese los numeros de la 1 lista:")))
c= (int(input("Ingrese los numeros de la 1 lista:")))
print ("Comienza la segunda lista")
d= (int(input("Ingrese los numeros de la 2 lista:")))
e= (int(input("Ingrese los numeros de la 2 lista:")))
f= (int(input("Ingrese los numeros de la 2 lista:")))
def combina(list1,list2,list3):
    combined = []
    for a in list1:
        new_list = []
        for b in list2 and list3:
            new_list.append([a, b])
        combined.append(new_list)   
    return combined

list1 = [a,b,c]
list2 = [d,e,f]
list3 = [a,b,c]
combined=combina(list1,list2,list3)
print(combined)
```

Comment: ¿podrías poner un [mcve] así como indicar qué falla en tu script actual?

Comment: ¿Qué resultado intentas obtener? [[ada][adb][adc][aea][aeb]... ]?